# How to run CronJob like every 20 minute of every hour from 8:20-23:00?

Tags: cron, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

my current cron-job is scheduled as ("0,20,40 8-23 * * *")
which runs At minute 20, 40, and 0 past every hour from 8 through 23.

My cron-job begins at 8:00am but I want to begin at 8:20 instead.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be `*/20 8-23 * * *`. If memory serves me correctly, it'll first run at 8:20 and run every 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this cron schedule: `*/20 8-23 * * *`
I tested that [here](https://crontab.guru/#*/20_8-23_*_*_*).

[image]

You can use https://crontab.guru/ for experimenting your cron schedule.